Help me identify this art nouveau font
I have tried to find it but the poster is too pixelated for software and the letters are warped. Please help.


Hi. Welcome to GDSE. It doesn't look like an art nouveau font to me. More like some kind of psychedelic font from the 1960's.  The date of the poster is 1967.  The Art Nouveau era was from around the 1890s to 1910s.

This is hand generated/drawn. It's not a "font". Anything created in the 1960s was not using "fonts" or computers.
